# Generating Lasso Path for Feature Selection

Tags: lasso, glmnet

I am building a Logistic regression model and exploring LASSO for feature selection. I generate the lasso path using the following code:

```
lasso_mod <- glmnet(x_vars,y,alpha=1,family='binomial')
plot(lasso_mod, xvar="lambda", label=T)
```

This is the plot that I get:

[image: LASSO PATH]

Now, I have couple of queries on this plot:

1. As the value of the tuning parameter (lambda) increases, you would expect more and more coefficients to progressively shrink towards zero. And this is what you do see in the plot, except for one variable (var. #8 - the one with the red line on the bottom half of the plot). The coefficient of this variable starts from zero and then moves to a non-zero value at higher values of lambda. Is this expected and if yes, what does this imply?
2. Secondly, I believe that there should be one line for each variable (including the dummy variable that gets created for categorical data). Now, as you can see in the plot there seems to be only 14 lines, but the number of variables that I have (incl. the dummy ones) is 17. And I can access it using the coef function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not expert on LASSO, so I will only leave this as a comment. For Q1, it could be because you have many highly correlated variables, which is difficult for LASSO to do variable selection on (elastic net is considered better for this because it keeps the "friends of important variables"). Are the variables highly correlated? Perhaps the 1 variable only re-enters the model when others are "kicked-out." For question 2, it could be that the coefficients were put to 0 at log lambdas below -7.5 (off of your chart).

Comment: I agree with Moose about the Q1, you have correlated predictors. About Q2, I think you have overlapping lines in the plot. Try plot ( ,,,, ylim=c(-0.1, 0.1) ) and maybe you will see the lines near of 0